# How to create and traverse a multidimensional list

Tags: list

I have code like this:

```el
(let* ((l1 '(1 2 3))
       (l2 '(4 5 6))
       (l3 '(7 8 9))
       (ml '(l1 l2 l3)))

  (dolist (l ml)
    (message "%s" l)
    (dolist (e l)
      (message "%s" e))))
```

But it does not work, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quote inhibits evaluation of what is inside the parentheses.

How about?

```lisp
(let* ((l1 '(1 2 3))
       (l2 '(4 5 6))
       (l3 '(7 8 9))
       (ml `(,l1 ,l2 ,l3)))
  (dolist (l ml)
    (message "%s" l)
    (dolist (e l)
      (message "%s" e))))
```

Or?

```lisp
(let* ((l1 '(1 2 3))
       (l2 '(4 5 6))
       (l3 '(7 8 9))
       (ml (list l1 l2 l3)))
  (dolist (l ml)
    (message "%s" l)
    (dolist (e l)
      (message "%s" e))))
```

See:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html